# Indian and Arabic Language support for Boilerplate

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, html5boilerplate

I'm using HTML5 Boilerplate template for creating a basic template for a CMS.  How can I make sure, this template can display Arabic language or any Indian language? I noticed there is  in header. But when I typed in Indian language it's not showing up, instead showing ???? marks.  Do I have to change the font-family from default Sans-Serif? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the encoding of my html file.  I'm using Notepad++ and it's encoding was 'Encode in UTF-8 without BOM'.  I changed that to 'Encode in UTF-8'.  Now it's fine.